# How to make 2 applications run each other in linux?

Tags: c++, linux, shell, process, nohup

The situation is as follows:

We have a main application and a watcher application.
Both of them are c++ applications. Both of them use daemon(1,0) function.

Watcher checks if main application is running and if it finds that main process is absent (crashed) or that main does not respond (applications 'talk' to each other through TCP and thats how it knows if it hung) then it runs the main or restarts it.

Now, TCP settings for the connection can be changed by the user, and it is done through main app. After the change, watcher must be restarted to load the new configuration. That is done from the main app.

As it is, it works fine.
1. On startup Main app DOES kill existing watcher process and runs it again. [This is correct]
2. Watcher app DOES kill main and runs it again. [This is correct]

BUT

1. If i run Main, which in turn starts Watcher,
2. then kill the Main so the Watcher is left alone.
3. Watcher sees that there is no Main anymore and so it starts it again.
4. Main starts again, kills the watcher and tries to start it again....
5. and at this point, some kind of nonesence happens. It starts the watcher (i can see that TCP port being taken through netstat command), but there is no process named watcher.

If normally netstat shows `tcp 0 0 IP:TCP_PORT LISTEN Watcher`, now it shows `tcp 0 0 IP:TCP_PORT LISTEN Main`.

It is as if watcher is there, but inside the Main process.

I use scripts to run applications.
Watcher uses this

```
#!/bin/sh
killall -9 Main
./Main
```

And runs it like `system("./runMain.sh&");`

Main uses this

```
#!/bin/sh
killall -9 Watcher
./Watcher
```

And runs it like `system("./runWatcher.sh&");`

What am i doing wrong? How do i run them so they could restart each other when needed and always start in separate processes?

So far i have also tried running the scripts using the `nohup`, result is the same.

**EDIT 1:**

Note: numbers here are just for clarity. In reality PID is not 1 of course.

1. I run Main. netstat shows me:

   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7000 LISTEN (PID 1)Main
   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7001 LISTEN (PID 1)Main
2. Main starts the Watcher using the script. Now netstat shows me:

   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7000 LISTEN (PID 1)Main
   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7001 LISTEN (PID 1)Main
   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:8000 LISTEN (PID 2)Watcher
3. Now, i manually kill Main by doing `killall -9 Main`. Now netstat shows me:

   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7000 LISTEN (PID 2)Watcher
   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7001 LISTEN (PID 2)Watcher
   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:8000 LISTEN (PID 2)Watcher

   Notice the change in who owns the listening sockets now? How did that happen?
4. Watcher sees that Main is gone and so it starts it using the script file.
5. Main kills the Watcher on startup. Netstat shows:

   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7000 LISTEN (PID 3)Main
   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:7001 LISTEN (PID 3)Main
   tcp 0 0 192.168.0.1:8000 LISTEN (PID 3)Main

And thats it. Watcher never runs again.
I tried to debug in Eclipse, Watcher crashes without throwing anything right on the line `daemon(1,0)`.

Comment: How do you know Watcher isn't starting but then terminating due to an error? Instrumenting your daemons with some logging to a file might be helpful.

Comment: Well, because Watcher is the only app using the TCP_PORT. Lets say its 8000. Main never listens to 8000, only the Watcher does. In the last case, however, it shows that main listens to 8000.

Comment: You stated `It is as if watcher is there, but inside the Main process.` but surely you know already that this isn't likely (and given how you're starting things... system() starts a shell, which then starts a new shell for your script, which then does whatever it does), you need to challenge the other things you're certain of and instead of assuming all is as it should be (since clearly it isn't), find positive proof of those things... such as Watcher starting and not then stopping.

Comment: See my edit 1. Its quite hard to debug, as it does not throw exceptions, nothing. It just terminates the app. I could place the breakpoint right on the `daemon()` line. 1 more step and it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a custom signal (or even listening on another port for admin commands)?  Using the kill -9 is playing with the process tree such as the child process gaining control of the parent's resources (ports, etc.)

Then, on top of that, when the Main process is started by the Watcher, why does it assume that the running instance of Watcher should be killed? One reason is now Watcher is the parent of Main, so I can see how that could cause trouble.

It comes down to the need for the two processes to communicate outside of the 'kill' signal.

### Use a semaphore or some other OS-level communication mechanism to coordinate between the two.

Comment: Hi, the idea is that watcher looks over the Main, so if main crashes or freezes, Watcher will start it again. They use a common configuration file, and when configuration is changed (Using Main) - watcher needs to be reloaded, thats why Main wants ti kill and restart watcher, so it loads new configs. I have changed the way Watcher works so that it checks for config changes if it sees Main is not responding to it the way it should. Thought it would be easier to just make it kill each other, but i was wrong.

Comment: Each one needs to be able to know when it should _NOT_ restart the other, in order to avoid these types of recursive actions.  Maybe the Main has an argument that Watcher uses when it is restarting Main, and when Main starts it checks that argument and if it's true Main skips restarting Watcher.